# Firebase Rules Confusion

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am getting very confused with the Firebase rules structure. Basically I have a root folder called 'Transactions', containing many childByAutoIDs that again contains data, exactly like this:

```
Transactions {
    autoID1 {
        transactionID: whatever,
        timeCreated: whatever,
        "amount": whatever,
        "sender": whatever,
        "receiver:whatever"
    }
}
```

I am now trying my best to implement the best possible security rules. I therefore tried to do something like this:

```
"Transactions": {
    ".write": "auth !== null",
    "$transactionAutoID": {
        "timeCreated": {
            ".write": "auth !== null && data.child('sender').val() === auth.uid || data.child('receiver').val() === auth.uid",
            ".read": "auth !== null && data.child('sender').val() === auth.uid || data.child('receiver').val() === auth.uid"
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, from what I have learned, and also what I am struggling with - is the fact that the user is able to write anything, even in the 'wildcard IDs ($transactionAutoID)'. I know this is because I have set the '.write' in Transactions to 'auth !== null' - but if I don't have this set, users may not read or write any transaction data. (I have the rules by default set to false).

How would I proceed if I only wanted users to be able to create new childs in Transactions, but not write in any transaction keys, if they are not either the sender or the receiver?

Answer (score 1):

Once a permission is granted on a node, it cannot be taken away on a lower-level node.

So if you look at this:

```
"Transactions": {
    ".write": "auth !== null",
    "$transactionAutoID": {
        "timeCreated": {
            ".write": "auth !== null && data.child('sender').val() === auth.uid || data.child('receiver').val() === auth.uid",
            ".read": "auth !== null && data.child('sender').val() === auth.uid || data.child('receiver').val() === auth.uid"
        }
    }
}
```

The write rule on `Transactions/$transactionId/timeCreated` is meaningless, since it tries to tighten the permission from `Transactions`.

So right now it functions like this:

```
"Transactions": {
    ".write": "auth !== null",
    "$transactionAutoID": {
        "timeCreated": {
            ".read": "auth !== null && data.child('sender').val() === auth.uid || data.child('receiver').val() === auth.uid"
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to put a limit to specifically what a user can do on `Transactions/$transactionId/timeCreated`, you will either have to do so in a validation rule or (more likely) by putting all the rules on the transaction itself:

```
"Transactions": {
    "$transactionAutoID": {
        ".write": "auth !== null && (
            !data.exists() || (
                newData.child('sender').val() === auth.uid ||
                newData.child('receiver').val() === auth.uid)"
            )
        )"
    }
}
```

In words: you can write a transaction when you're authenticated and *either* the transaction doesn't exist yet *or* you're the sender or receiver of the transaction.

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks for sorting this out. However, considering I have my default settings to false, won't I be rejected trying to make a new child under the 'Transaction' then? Because I only have a write rule inside the wildCardID INSIDE Transactions?

Comment: The rules I've provided will allow you to add a specific transaction. Try it. If you're having trouble making it work, show the code of the operation that fails (or at the very least, the location that you write to and the JSON that you're writing).

Comment: I see. However, I am also curious (if) it's possible to define a new write permission inside the unique transaction? And by the way, I did unfortunately not make it work. Error message: 'Simulator request denied'.